# Golang NewChunkedReader Usage

Tags: go, chunked-encoding, http-chunked

I'm attempting to process a chunked response from a 3rd-party service by introducing it to `httputil.NewChunkedReader`:

```
chunkedReader := httputil.NewChunkedReader(chunkedResponse)

buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
buf.ReadFrom(chunkedReader)
return buf.Bytes()
```

This code returns zero bytes, as does manually invoking `reader.Read`.

I'm looking for a practical example in terms of implementing `httputil.NewChunkedReader`.

Comment: "header line too long"

Comment: @PaulMooney [ErrLineTooLong is returned when reading malformed chunked data with lines that are too long](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#pkg-variables). Are you sure your data is not malformed?

Comment: @Ainar-G No, the payload is definitely not malformed. Both Postman and Fiddler display it without issue.

Comment: Where do you get `chunkedResponse` from?

Comment: A proprietary service – unfortunately I can’t offer more than a code snippet:  `34f0{"otherServiceInfoList":[],"...0`

Comment: Yes, it's returned from the net/http package, without any special encoding, etc.

Comment: When you say "above the HTTP layer" are you referring to some form of encoding applied before the payload is sent down the wire?

Comment: Yes, that's the code that I had originally implementated. I modified it to leverage `httputil` because Fiddler offered an encoded response warning. The object of the exercise was to understand the inner workings, more than anything else.

Comment: Do you have a sample of the chunked response? It sounds like it's not properly encoded. Otherwise, it works as advertised: http://play.golang.org/p/OBkZJRzIfd